# How to identify files with no ext in its name but has extension in its property for example: nav.example.file which is actually a text document

Tags: linux, shell

`find -maxdepth 1 ! -name "*.*" -print`

This is not identifying file names like INSSO.TEST.20100503.16400006 which is a xml document

Comment: Well, obviously that file has a `16400006` extension. Or do you want to identify file names whose extension is no more than 3 characters long? What about the `.git` directory? Is that a file with no extension?

Comment: What do you mean by _has extension it its property_?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas wouldn't `.git` be an extension with no file?

Comment: What do you mean by "_This is not identifying file names like INSSO.TEST.20100503.16400006_"? There's no identification step in the `find` statement you've give us. It will simply list all files in the current directory that contain a dot in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find files based on what's in them -- not on their names -- you will need to look in them.  **find** won't do that on its own, but you can tell it execute another program that will.

I would start with **file**(1), which will print out some description of the file.  If it's useful for your XML files, I would write a script that prints the filename if **find** says it's the right type.  Then invoke that script for all eligible files with:

```
find . -type f -exec my-xml-detector {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find files in the current directory that have no extension or an extension that is more than 3 characters long, or an empty extension, you could do:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '?*.[!.]' \
                        ! -name '?*.[!.][!.]' \
                        ! -name '?*.[!.][!.][!.]'
```

(that assumes no file name contains byte sequences that don't form valid characters).